# Como separa la parte real y parte compleja de un numero complejo AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'real'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy graficando la parte real e imaginaria de un número complejo. Para esto realize un loop for para separar ambos números pero estoy obteniendo el error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'real'. Como puedo solucionar esta problema. Y adicional como puedo graficar la parte imaginaria en Python.

Este es el código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


a = float(input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: "))
rho = 1.2
c = 340
fs = [31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000]

ks = [(2 * math.pi * f) / c for f in fs]
zmr = [rho * c * ((1j * k * a) / (1 + (1j * k * a))) for k in ks]
for i in range(len(zmr)):
      rzmr=zmr.real
      izmr=zmr.imag
plt.title("Impedancia de radiación")
plt.plot(fs, zmr,'b--')
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Impedancia Mecanica')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imag` y `real` no son atributos del objeto `list`, aunque si son son métodos de los objetos `complex` que tu lista contiene.

Debes iterar sobre la lista e ir obteniendo ambos atributos de cada objeto. Puedes usar una expresión generadora con `zip`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

a = float(input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: "))
rho = 1.2
c = 340
fs = [31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000]

ks = [(2 * math.pi * f) / c for f in fs]
zmr = [rho * c * ((1j * k * a) / (1 + (1j * k * a))) for k in ks]

real, imaginaria = zip(*((c.real, c.imag) for c in zmr))
```

De una forma más "convencional" sería equivalente a:

```
real = []
imaginaria = []

for c in zmr:
    real.append(c.real)
    imaginaria.append(c.imag)
```

Otra opción sería usar `numpy.real` y `numpy.imag`, aunque en este caso  te recomiendo que uses NumPy desde el principio y te aproveches de las capacidades de 
vectorización que ofrece (aplicar una operación sobre el array completo sin iterar explícitamente).

```
import numpy as np

a = float(input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: "))
rho = 1.2
c = 340
fs = np.array((31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000))
ks = (2 * np.pi * fs) / c
zmr = (rho * c * ((1j * ks * a) / (1 + (1j * ks * a))))
real = np.real(zmr)
imaginaria = np.imag(zmr)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eres un pro man.